# RAD Studio. Редактор кода. Что-то нажалось

Tags: ide, delphi-10.3-rio

Что-то случайно нажал и при выделении строки и последующем нажатии на любую букву, выделенная строка не удаляется, а символ печатается рядом.

Как исправить?

P.S. Используется Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3.1 RIO

Comment: 1. Выйти и войти. 2. Переставить студию. :-)

Comment: Может клавиша Ins нажалась? Еще раз ее нажать.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 переустановка ничего не дала - настройки где-то суки хранятся в реестре

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не, прикол не в том, что при вводе слова удаляются последующие, а НАОБОРОТ.
Вот я выделил строку и нажал ctrl+v (в буфере другая строка), так вот, вместо замены, я получаю две строки (вставка слева от выделенного)

Comment: Причем для удаления обнаружил, что работает ctrl + DEL

Comment: Переустановка не дала? Да это вообще беспредел, что за программа, которая при переустановке не приходит в исходное состояние? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Отвечу себе сам.
>
> Для сброса Rad Studio 10.3 к дефолтным настройкам удаляем раздел
>   реестра HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0
>
> После перегрузки системы все будет OK.

[Взято от сюда](http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/5433-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-rad-studio-103/)

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->User Interface->Editor

Убрать или поставить галочку Overwrite bloks

И да будет вам счастье

Comment: а ведь уже  есть ответ